# Number type : addtion in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to programming i am learning javascript on w3 schools and come to know that

```
var x = 0.2+0.1; // result will be 0.30000000000000004
alert(x);
```

how it is possible. Please let me know

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)